# How to get cropping functionality on front-end image upload?

Tags: image, crop

Need to have users upload images on front-end via Safecracker but they need to be a specific width and height - otherwise could just limit the width - so really is going to need some cropping functionality.

Anyone done this? Add-ons? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at CE_img (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-image) ? It doesn't allow the uploader to crop the image but you can apply some parameters to crop and specify whether you crop from the centre, edge etc. It also lets you resize and apply effects to the images as well as caching them. On the whole it's very useful.

Comment: This option of course does the cropping when the image is displayed again on the frontend vs actually during upload. Not sure that matters though, thought I'd clarify a tad over what @foamcow said :)

Comment: +1 for CE Image. If custom user cropping on upload isn't a requirement, CE Image is superb.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this previously using Safecracker Dev Demon's Channel Images, http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images/

As a bonus the GUI Channel Images uses is very nice and allows multiple uploads and upload progress.

Just my 2 cents.